# Grails - Bulk Update table rows using a column of checkboxes

Tags: grails

I have a table whose rows can be modified in-line. There is a submit button column at the end of each row. This works fine, as I loop through the backing list of domain objects, put each  in a form, and submit them individually that way.

My problem arises when I add a column of checkboxes to allow the user to bulk update multiple rows. The button for the bulk update operation is outside that table, and also the forms of each row. How do I get the backing domain objects of the selected rows when I hit the Bulk Update button outside the table?

I realise I could probably add a field to the domain objects specifically for the checkbox but I don't want to have to do that as it seem messy and just a consequence of the UI I have to use instead of serving a functional purpose.

Thanks in advance for any help, let me know if you need more information!

Tony

Comment: Will you please shouw your code? No one can even know WHAT tabel are you using, is it Ajax on HTML, and so on.

Comment: Hi Victor, thanks for responding. In future questions I'll show my code, what I have tried so far, etc. I'm new to the site. FYI, a solution was posted below. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Don't keep one form for each row, keep it as one big form.
2. Give each checkbox the same 'name', and on the backend you can access it as a list. 
   Example: <g:checkbox name="selectedRow" />
3. Similarly give each input field in each column the same name also. For example, give all textboxes which take the input of age in all the rows the same name.
4. Now on the backend all the column inputs can be accessed as groovy lists.
5. Extract the checkbox inputs by doing 'params.selectedRow' (selectedRow was the name given to our checkboxes above)
6. now in that list find the checkboxes which have value true, match the indexes of this checkbox list with the rest of the inputs, and update them.

I've tried to make this answer as detailed as possible, let me know if you didnt understand any part.

Comment: Hi Atharva, sorry it took so long to mark your question as correct. It worked perfectly and is much appreciated! Thanks a million!